# What is the redirect_uri if I have android app in Unity (OAuth 2.0)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, authentication, oauth-2.0, registration

I have to implement login and register functions in my mobile application in `Unity` (`c#`) using `OAuth 2.0`.

Bbut there is a problem with understanding and scripting. Since it is not a web app, I can't understand what is the `redirect_uri` for getting authorization code and token after it.

It would be nice if somebody could provide the answer with example.

Comment: what is the redirect_uri in Mobile App flow when it wants to send the credentials (i.e. access token and refresh token) toward the backend side? is it a backend endpoint or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom URL schemes for the final callback as it's done client side, so what you do is register a URL scheme for your app to capture requests to.

As per the official [OAuth 2 documentation](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/redirect-uris/redirect-uris-native-apps/).

In Unity this will mean interacting with platform specific APIs to achieve. You'll need to check with the Unity documentation for how this is achieved.

Comment: what is the redirect_uri in Mobile App flow when it wants to send the credentials (i.e. access token and refresh token) toward the backend side? is it a backend endpoint or not?

Comment: On a mobile app flow you'd capture the navigate event of an embedded browser window to capture the token.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your question is about redirecturi or about redirecturi in Unity. :)

RedirectURI is used when you use Authorization Code grant type or Implicit Grant of oAuth2, while the authentication and authorization is done by a 3rd party server. When a login screen is shown by a 3rd party website(like google), once the user is authenticated, it should know when the flow should go back.

May [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51755762/how-does-a-mobile-app-authenticate-with-a-backend-api-if-the-user-signs-in-throu/51771378#51771378) also helps

Comment: what is the redirect_uri in Mobile App flow when it wants to send the credentials (i.e. access token and refresh token) toward the backend side? is it a backend endpoint or not?